# css ul shape next to li

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

Can someone tell me how to get the shapes for ul li to align next to a li.
I have an section that is floated to the left and the text is centered within the floated section.
I add a ul, but the square are off to the side of the page and not next to the li items.
Sounds simple enough.

styleSheet.css

```
#SectionOne {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
#SectionOne ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
#subPage {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

subPage.php

```
<body id="subPage">
<section id="SectionOne">
    <h4><b> January 1st 2015</b>
    </h4>
    <p>Related Title</p>
    item1<br>
    item2<br>
    item3<br>
    <p><h3>List Title</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Bullet Item One</li>
            <li>Bullet Item Two</li>
            <li>Bullet Item Three</li>
        </ul>
    </p>

</section> 
</section>
</body>
```

The section 'SectionOne' floats left and aligns centered was I wish, but when I add the style to the 'ul' the bullets are left justified.  Is there a way to keep them close to the line items?  Or should I create another section for the 'ul' alone?

Comment: Can you clarify your question some more? There are a few ways to interpret what you're asking at the moment.

Comment: It's of utmost important that you show relevant code when asking a question.